# Did this ever compile?

Tags: .net, msdn

I just saw this on an [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100813-00/?p=13153):

```
class Sample1 {
 private StreamReader sr;
 public Sample1(string file) : sr(new StreamReader(file)) { }
 public void Close() { sr.Close(); }
 public string NextLine() { return sr.ReadLine(); }
}
```

It doesn't compile (assuming it's C#) because you can't call the constructor of the `StreamReader` like that.

- Is this just a mistake of the author?
- If not, why does it compile (did it used to compile or is it not C#)?

Comment: No, that's not legal C#, it's C++ most likely.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Good point, that reads much better.  Cheers.

Comment: Raymond Chen is not a C# fan and is only occasionally interested in blogging about managed code subjects.  C++ is his weapon of choice. Fumbling the C# code with C++ semantics is the somewhat inevitable outcome.